# Golang Type Assertion Arrays

Tags: go, type-assertion

For what I understand type assertion can only be used in interfaces and basically check if a determined type implements the interface.

I am having some weird scenarios:

```
func binder(value interface{}) {
   // Does not work
   valueInt, ok := value.(int)

   // Works
   valueInt, ok := value.(float64)

   // Does not work 
   coordinates, ok := value.([]int)

   // Does not work 
   coordinates, ok := value.([]float64) 
}
```

Basically, my `value` is an empty interface and I am getting from a `json.Unmarshall`.

**Scenario 1**

when I pass a simple integer it does not work but if I check if is a float it works...

**Scenario 2**

When I pass an array of int or floats does not work! As you can see when I am debugging I am receiving an array but for some reason assertion does not work.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"?  What output did you receive? What did you expect instead?

Comment: Does not work means `ok` is false! But your answer below makes everything clear for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but it appears to boil down to the following:

By default, `json.Unmarshal` unmarshals all numbers into float64, since all numbers in JSON are floats. If you want some other type, you need to use a specific type in your target type. Examples:

```
var x map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"foo":123}`), &x) // { "foo": float64(123) }
```

vs:

```
var x map[string]int64
json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"foo":123}`), &x) // { "foo": int64(123) }
```

And by default, all JSON arrays unmarshal to `[]interface{}`, because the members can be of any type, including mixed types. If you want a specific type, again, you have to be specific:

```
var x interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(`[1,2,3]`), &x) // []interface{}{float64(1), float64(2), float64(3)}
```

vs:

```
var x []int64
json.Unmarshal([]byte(`[1,2,3]`), &x) // []int64{1,2,3}
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you very much!! I cannot unmarshal at that point so I would need to iterate the `[]interface{}` array and check if all values are float!